# Problem with loading social navigation layer plugins on costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, 2dcostmap, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am currently using layered costmaps, specifically i am trying to use the social_navigation_layer as described here: http://wiki.ros.org/social_navigation_layers.
The problem is that i can't figure it out what i do wrong; the plugin does not start.
These are my .yaml files:

1. costmap_common_params.yaml

   obstacle_range: 2.5
   raytrace_range: 5.0
   footprint: [[0.36,0.0], [0.28, 0.24],[0, 0.36], [-0.47, 0.15], [-0.47,-0.15], [0.0,-0.36], [0.28,-0.24]]

   #robot_radius: ir_of_robot
   inflation_radius: 0.45
   cost_scaling_factor: 10

   cost_factor: 0.8
   neutral_cost: 50
   lethal_cost: 253

   obstacle_layer:
   observation_sources: ale_scan
   ale_scan: {data_type: LaserScan, sensor_frame: /robot/frontLaser/MountFrame, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /ale_scan}
2. global_costmap_params.yaml

   global_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: base_link
   update_frequency: 10.0
   resolution: 0.05
   static_map: true

   plugins:
   - {name: footprint_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::FootprintLayer"}
   - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer", output: "screen"}
   - {name: static_map,             type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
   - {name: obstacle_layer,        type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer", output: "screen"}
   - {name: social_layer,           type: "social_navigation_layers::ProxemicLayer", output: "screen"}
   - {name: social_pass_layer,   type: "social_navigation_layers::PassingLayer", output: "screen"}
3. local_costmap_params.yaml

   local_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_link
   update_frequency: 10.0
   publish_frequency: 10.0
   rolling_window: true
   width: 6.0
   height: 6.0
   resolution: 0.05

   plugins:
   - {name: footprint_layer,        type: "costmap_2d::FootprintLayer", output: "screen"}
   - {name: inflation_layer,        type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer", output: "screen"}
   - {name: obstacle_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer", output: "screen"}
   - {name: social_layer,           type: "social_navigation_layers::ProxemicLayer", output: "screen"}
   - {name: social_pass_layer,      type: "social_navigation_layers::PassingLayer", output: "screen"}

and this is the launch file:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <arg name="map_file" default="$(find ale_coro)/launch/corridoio.yaml"/>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

<!--- Run AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch" />
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find ale_coro)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find ale_coro)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find ale_coro)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find ale_coro)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find ale_coro)/launch/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
     </node>
</launch>
```

When i launch it, only the footprint, obstacles and inflation layers are loaded.
When i try to find the parameters of the social_navigation_layer, there is no trace of them.
For that reason when i use rviz, the person is tracked correctly but there is no effect of the proxemic or passing layer.

Can you guys help me, please?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253091/problem-with-loading-social-navigation-layer-plugins-on-costmap/) by [alefag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29172/alefag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect that the `plugins` param is not under the correct namespace. Not sure why the other layers do get loaded though.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alefag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29172/alefag/) on 2017-01-30**:
Hi and thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but i'm starting programming with ros, so i ask you: how do i check o change the namespace?
Thank you

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-01-30**:
One way would be this: After launching everything, type `rosparam list | grep plugins` and visually inspect the path / namespace of the relevant parameters.

**Comment by [alefag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29172/alefag/) on 2017-01-31**:
I tried and i got:
/costmap_node/costmap/plugins
/move_base/global_costmap/plugins
/move_base/local_costmap/plugins
/move_base/plugins

Typing `rosparam get /move_base/local_costmap/plugins` , returns only two layers, the obstacle and the inflation layer, but there are no trace of others.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-01-31**:
That's what I suspected. In your two `*_costmap_params.yaml`, place `plugins` under `global_costmap:` and `local_costmap:`. Just like you've done with your other parameters. It's YAML, so indentation matters!

**Comment by [alefag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29172/alefag/) on 2017-01-31**:
Exactly that was the problem, thanks for your help!

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-01-31**:
Glad I could help @alefag :-) Could you please click on the checkmark icon next to my answer, which will mark it as accepted? Thanks